# BluetoothManger no link with Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, ios9.3

I embedded the private framework `BluetoothManager.framework` with headers in path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`, with the includes

```
#import <BluetoothManager/BluetoothManager.h>
#import <BluetoothManager/BluetoothDevice.h>
```

but since Xcode 7.3 there is an error:

`error :ld: framework not found BluetoothManager`.

Comment: Solution provided [in answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37001091/119114)

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned in the Apple release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html) private frameworks (and also `BluetoothManager.framework` are removed from the SDK iOS 9.3. This is why it does not work any more.